# Retrieve multiple serial port in same time using background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

i want to ask about read data from serial port using background worker. Is it possible to retrieve data from one serial port or more using one worker? I can retrieve data when only use one serial port in worker. When i use two or more ports, i can't retrieve data anymore (without error message). Here is my code :

```
  private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
        String p = "";
        String s = "";
        Int32 b = 0;
        MethodInvoker get_selectedPort = new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                p = comboBoxPressure.SelectedItem.ToString();
                s = comboBoxStrain.SelectedItem.ToString();
                b = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxBaudrate.SelectedItem.ToString());
            });
        this.Invoke(get_selectedPort);

        SerialPort portPressure = new SerialPort();  // serial port 1
        portPressure.PortName = p;
        portPressure.BaudRate = b;
        portPressure.Parity = Parity.None;
        portPressure.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        portPressure.DataBits = 8;
        portPressure.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        SerialPort portStrain = new SerialPort(); // serial port 2
        portStrain.PortName = s;
        portStrain.BaudRate = b;
        portStrain.Parity = Parity.None;
        portStrain.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        portStrain.DataBits = 8;
        portStrain.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        try
        {
            portPressure.Open();
            portStrain.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while trying open serial port!\r\n" + error.Message, "COM Port Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            worker.CancelAsync();
            return;
        }

        while (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {               
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.dataPressure = portPressure.ReadExisting();
            this.dataStrain = portStrain.ReadExisting();
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => updateData()));
        }

        portPressure.Close();
        portStrain.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to make things so complicated?  Just make two threads, one for each port.

Comment: Pretty unclear.  When you use Handshake.None then it is up to you to turn on the handshake lines.  Set DtrEnable and RtsEnable to true.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need retrieve data from these ports in same time, so i think they must be opened in same worker. I need these data in pair, because i will plot them in graph.

Comment: I'm very suspicious of your lack of `using` blocks.

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive when reading from two ports simultaneously? There's no technical reason you shouldn't be able to do that. @JohnSaunders : It looks like he's closing the ports properly. Using blocks might be clearer, but is there something incorrect with this code?

Comment: @Andrew: `using` blocks will ensure the ports get closed even in the case of an exception. I'm concerned about what happens if an unhandled exception occurs in that code, running in a separate thread, called from an event. I would be concerned that the exception might not be clearly visible.

Comment: You are making bad assumptions about your ability to read from the ports as a pair.  Serial data is just asynchronous byte streams.  There is no guarantee that all of your data available on both ports at the same time.

Comment: I'd think you'd be better off reading from each port on its own thread and then aggregating the data when they're both done.